# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVAudioInputNode' // Swift 4.2

Tags: swift

This code:

```
guard let node = audioEngine.inputNode else { return }
```

Results in the following error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVAudioInputNode'

What should I change to make it work?

Tried to delete `guard` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the `guard let node = audioEngine.inputNode ...` is trying to unwrap an optional value. However, `audioEngine.inputNode` does not return an optional value.

If you just do `let node = audioEngine.inputNode` (without the `guard let return`), it will work.